# Laravel - Company Logo is not displayed in index view blade

Tags: laravel

I am developing a project using Laravel-5.8. I have been able to store the image successfully in storage as shown below:

**Controller**

```
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
{
abort_unless(\Gate::allows('company_create'), 403);
try {    
        $orgStartDate = Carbon::parse($request->org_start_date);          

        $arr = [
            'organization_code'     => $request->organization_code,
            'organization_name'     => $request->organization_name,
        ];

         if ($request->org_image != "") {
            $image = $request->file('org_image');
            $picName = time() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $imagePath = '/storage/companies/image';
            $image->move(public_path($imagePath), $picName);
            $arr['org_image'] = 'storage/companies/image/' . $picName;
        }               

        $company = OrgCompany::create($arr);
        Session::flash('success', 'Company is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('organization.companies.index');                

} catch (Exception $exception) {
        Session::flash('danger', 'Action failed!');
        return redirect()->route('organization.companies.index');  
}
}

public function index()
{
    $companies = OrgCompany::all();

    return view('admin.companies.index', compact('companies'));
}
```

The image is stored successfully, and the field name is org_image, which is a varchar.

[image: image location]

However, when I wanted to retrieve and view any of the store image through the index.blade.php, nothing is being displayed. It was blank.

**index.blade.php**

```html
  <tbody>
     @foreach($companies as $key => $company)
         <tr data-entry-id="{{ $company->id }}">
             <td>
                 {{ $company->organization_code ?? '' }}
             </td>
             <td>
                 {{ $company->organization_name ?? '' }}
             </td>
             <td>                             
                 <img src="app/public/storage/companies/image/{{ $company->org_image }}" alt="" height="100">
             </td>

        </tr>
     @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

Where have I missed it and how do I view the image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has a nifty helper method, `asset()`, to get you to the right path within that public folder for your image.

In your **Blade** file, try this:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('storage/companies/image/'.$company->org_image)}}"
```

This assumes you have stored the name of the image in the company object variable (`$company->org_image`) as the correct `1577281236_logo.png`.

Looks like you are storing it in a different variable possibly:

```
$picName = time() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
```

You might wish to consider calling `$company->picName` in the `asset()` method above, to ensure you get *just* the name of the file.   Instead, you've currently got the whole path stored inside `org_image` (`storage/companies/image/`).  This is further complicating the call to get the image, as it is doubling up with your current `<img src>` call, essentially calling this:

```
src="app/public/storage/companies/image/storage/companies/image/1577281236_logo.png"
```

Also - note your index is calling `$countries` and compacting `companies`.  I assume this is a typo :)